# Linux, check if a temporary file gets created then deleted

Tags: linux, file, tmp

I am trying to debug a problem on my server with wkhtmltopdf on a Django application.

The command generated to run wkhtml is pointing at a file in /tmp/.

```
wkhtmltopdf.sh --encoding utf8--quiet/tmp/wkhtmltopdffa46k_h8.html -
```

Is there an easy way to check if the file gets created in /tmp then deleted? (As it isn't present after the web request has completed).

Comment: Perhaps you should show your `wkhtmltopdf.sh` script. Is there any reason you can't modify it to `echo "File Created..."`?

Answer (score 4):

The tool to debug such things is called `strace`. Run:

```
strace -f wkhtmltopdf.sh --encoding utf8--quiet/tmp/wkhtmltopdffa46k_h8.html
```

Explanation:

A program in order to create, write, close, delete a file needs to call kernel code in order to achieve that. This kernel functions are called *system calls*. `strace` will run the program and prints any system call the command makes to stderr(!).

This might give you a little bit too much information if you read it unfiltered. If you want to `grep` for the filename of the tempfile, keep in mind that `strace` writes to stderr:

```
strace -f program ... 2>&1 | grep filename
```

---

PS: Alternatively `inotifywait` from the package `inotify-tools` can be used:

```
inotifywait -m --format "%e %f" /tmp
```

Better explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164801/45365

Comment: Its all being run as part of a Django request, so its not going to be easy to use strace. I can run the comand manually and everything is fine, but fails when incoprorated into teh Django app.

Comment: Ok, then I recommend `inotifytools`. Let me prepare something. You are on Linux I assume?

Comment: I saw another answer on serverfault that suggested making the directory append only: chattr -a /tmp/. Not the cleanest way to do it, but I can now see that the temporary file isn't being generated.

Comment: `inotifywait -m --format "%e %f" /tmp` will do the trick. (you need to install inotify-tools) Check this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164801/45365

Comment: Btw, if the django server is not under heavy load, you can also get it's PID and run (as root) `strace -fp PID`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
watch -n0,1 "ls -lrt /tmpdir/ | tail"
```